# Include tasks in file before the file exists

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that includes two other files:

```
 - include: myFile1.yml
 - include: myRepo/myFile2.yml
```

The problem is that `myRepo` is a git repository checked out by one of the tasks in `myFile1.yml`, so `myFile2.yml` doesn't exists unless the tasks in `myFile.yml` complete successfully.

Ansible has a problem with this, of course, because it tries to parse the file even though it doesn't exist and returns an error. Does ansible have any way to defer parsing the file until *after* the tasks in the first included file complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to work around this was to make `myRepo` a submodule repository of the repository containing `myFile1.yml`. This way, when the main repo is checked out, the repository containing the other playbook is also checked out automatically. This might not work for all other situations, but it worked here. The other option was to glue everything together with shell scripts and try to generate playbooks on the fly, but that seemed a lot more complicated...

Answer (score 0):

This is marginally related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/__NS97GEyDY

If it's really important that a part of your effective playbook is checked out fresh from git, I would consider using ansible-pull (for which there will be a slight curve unfortunately, around inventory IIRC).

In short, I do not believe there is any workaround on version 1.8.2.